# ZeroDivisionError Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def do_timelapse(self, cmd):
    self.final_fps = input("What will your final edit be at(FPS)?\n")
    self.frame_interval = input("What is your Camera's Frame interval(Sec)")
    self.original_frame_fps = 1/self.frame_interval
    self.small_original = self.original_frame_fps/100
    self.percentage = self.final_fps/self.small_original
    print self.percentage
```

How do i resolve this error:

```
self.percentage = self.final_fps/self.small_original
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero ?
```

Comment: `self.original_frame_fps/100`: integer division python 2. => `self.original_frame_fps/100.0`

Answer (score 3):

```
self.frame_interval = input("What is your Camera's Frame interval(Sec)")
```

it returns an integer, means that you're using python 2. So the next line

```
self.original_frame_fps = 1/self.frame_interval
```

probably issues 0 if `self.frame_interval` > 1

```
self.small_original = self.original_frame_fps/100
```

so `self.small_original` is zero

```
self.percentage = self.final_fps/self.small_original
```

so it crashes.

Fix: work with *floats*:

```
self.original_frame_fps = 1.0/self.frame_interval
```

and

```
self.small_original = self.original_frame_fps/100.0
```

(of course check that `self.frame_interval` isn't `0` either)

Alternatives:

1. use python 3, with just a small fix (and still the check for zero):

   self.final_fps = int(input("What will your final edit be at(FPS)?\n"))
   self.frame_interval = int(input("What is your Camera's Frame interval(Sec)"))

since `input` returns strings now (like `raw_input` does in python 3)

2. use python 3 division in python 2: add this at the start of your file:

   `from __future__ import division`

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is you are using Python 2.7 which returns an integer value on division of two `int`. For example:

```
>>> 5 / 100
0
```

That is the reason the value of `self.small_original` is getting set as 0. In order to fix it, you need to type-cast any of the numerator or denominator to `float` as:

```
>>> float(5) / 100
0.05  # returns float value
```

Hence, you need to update the line in your code with:

```
self.original_frame_fps = 1.0/self.frame_interval
#               float here ^
```

and

```
self.small_original = self.original_frame_fps/100.0
#                                  float value  ^
```

Comment: first there's `self.original_frame_fps = 1.0/self.frame_interval`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Thanks for pointing. I had already changed it :)